# How to Convert Q Object of Django Queryset into SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

Suppose we have a Q expression like this:

```
Q(price__lt=160) | Q(publishing_date__year__gte=2016)
```

The SQL expression for this expression would be:

```
price < 160 OR YEAR(publishing_date) >= 2016
```

I want a package which converts these `Q` objects of Django into the SQL equivalent. Like:

```
q_obj = Q(price__lt=160) | Q(publishing_date__year__gte=2016)
sql_expression = q_obj_to_sql(q_obj) # Please, recommend if there exists such a thing
```

***Note:*** *Although Django provides a way to convert Querysets into SQL, but, I need to convert `Q` objects, and not the Querysets.*

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
# is a model expample
class MyModel(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    publishing_date = models.DateField()
    ...


from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.sql.compiler import SQLCompiler
from django.db import connection

# your Q filter
_filter = Q(price__lt=160) | Q(publishing_date__year__gte=2016)
_query = Query(MyModel) # replace "MyModel" with your model

_compiler = SQLCompiler(_query, connection, None)
query_str, args = _filter.resolve_expression(_query).as_sql(_compiler, connection)
# query_str is a string, the result is 
#        '("my_model"."price" < %s OR "my_model"."publishing_date" >= %s)'
# args is a list, result is
#         [160, '2016-01-01']

# for replace arguments in query_str
result = query_str % tuple(args)
# WARNING , don't do this !! Security issue with sql injections.
# result :
#     '("my_model"."price" < 160 OR "my_model"."publishing_date" >= 2016-01-01)'
```

Comment: In that case, I need to have a model and the fields mentioned in the `Q` query must be there in the model. But, the scenario I have is that I don't have any model. I just have some Django lookups and I need to convert them to SQL. It should be independent of the definition of the model.

Comment: django need modelsto construct queryset and Q filter for check/replace field with modelsfield , if you not have any models , you c'ant do this with django